# why session data not being destroy?

Tags: php, session

I have some simple php simple scripts.   One is to display login user, and the other one is to log out.  These are code fragments from a larger file.   Anyway, first I executed the login script and enter the user name, the user name showed up fine.   Next I executed the logout.  If I entered the login page again, i would expected the login_user to be empty, but it is not.  The older login_user name is still there.  If I clear the cache  and bring up the login page again, the login_user is gone.   How do I clear the session data for good?   Here is the login.php

```
<?php

  session_start();
  $_SESSION['myerror']="XXX";

  displayLoginUser();

  function displayLoginUser()
  {
     if (isset ($_SESSION['login_user']))
     {
        echo $_SESSION['login_user'];
     }
  } // end displayLoginUser
?>
```

Here is the logout.php

```
<?php

// NOTE none of the statements below seem to clear the login_user    
$_SESSION['login_user'] = " ";

unset ($_SESSION['login_user']);

session_destroy();

header("location: library.php");
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TRY THIS:**

```
session_start();
$_SESSION = array();
session_destroy();
```

will completely destroy the session and all its variables no need to `unset()` or anything else

Comment: The $_SESSION = array()  did not work.   Here is some extra info,  I am running this on MAC safari browser.  I also tried the chrome browser, same problem.  The web server that I am using is Apache.

Comment: First are you missing a semicolon after array()
$_SESSION = array(); is working fine for me ... did you get any error or the user stays logged in even after you applied my solution?

Comment: Ok, I see my mistake now.   I left out the session_start statement.  Thank you.